# Formulation of spectral norm minimization as a semidefinite program

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, spectral-norm

Given a matrix $F \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ such that $m > n$ and other (non-symmetric) square matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$, how can one formulate

$$ \arg \min_b \left\|A- {F}^{*} \operatorname{diag} \left( b \right) \, {F}  \right\|_{2}$$

where $b \in \mathbb{C}^m$ is some vector and $*$ denotes the conjugate transpose, as a semidefinite program?

I started as follows. Writing the above problem in epigraph form by introducing a variable $x$,

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x\\ \text{subject to} & \left\|A- {F}^{*} \operatorname{diag} \left( b \right) \, {F}  \right\|_{2} \leq x\end{array}

which is equivalent to

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x\\ \text{subject to} & \sigma_{\max}(A- {F}^{*} \operatorname{diag} \left( b \right) \, {F}  ) \leq x\end{array}

which is equivalent to

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x\\ \text{subject to} & \lambda_{\max}\big((A- {F}^{*} \operatorname{diag} \left( b \right) \, {F}  )^*(A- {F}^{*} \operatorname{diag} \left( b \right) \, {F}  ) \big) \leq x^2\end{array}

Can anybody tell me how I can proceed with this?

Comment: A key concept is that $F^{T}\mbox{diag}(b)F=\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i} (F_{i}^{T}F_{i})$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137408/339790).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo So I have reached this step: $ \begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x\\ \text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} x I & A - F^*\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(b) F \\ A^* - F^*\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(conj(b)) F & x I \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0_{2n}\end{array}$. How do I proceed after this?

Comment: @abinashr Don't you have an SDP in $x$ and $b$ already? Next step would be to solve it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I want to ask a stupid question. Is there an analytic way to solve this problem to begin with?

Comment: @abinashr I do not know. I have never solved an SDP analytically. I usually use numerical solvers. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2776808/339790)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to approach this. One is to recognize that
$$\sigma_\max(X)\leq y \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \begin{bmatrix} yI & X \\ X^T & yI \end{bmatrix}
\succeq 0$$
So the constraint becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix} x I & A - F^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(b) F \\ A - F^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(b) F & x I \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$$
Another way is to recognize that, for a symmetric matrix,
$$\sigma_\max(X) = \max\{-\lambda_\min(X),\lambda_\max(X)\}$$
And with that, we could do
$$ -x  I \preceq  A - F^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(b)F  \preceq x I$$
The latter will be preferred because a pair of LMIs is more performant than one twice the size.

Comment: For complex case, does it simply become $ \begin{bmatrix} x I & A - F^*\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(b) F \\ A^* - F^*\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(conj(b)) F & x I \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\begin{bmatrix} yI & X \\ X^T & yI \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$?

Comment: yes, thanks Rodrigo!

Comment: @abinashr in the complex case, yes that's fine. But note that if $b$ is not real, you lose Hermitian symmetry, so you can't use the second more compact form.

Comment: @MichaelGrant could you please explain why can't I write it in the more compact form if $b$ is complex?

Comment: @abinashr Even if $A$ were Hermitian, $b_i = b_i^*$ only if $b_i \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Actually I don't quite understand how does one arrive to this expression $-x  I \preceq  A - F^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(b)F  \preceq x I$ from $\begin{bmatrix} x I & A - F^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(b) F \\ A - F^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(b) F & x I \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$. Could you please explain?

Comment: @abinashr One does not. If $A$ is symmetric, use the former. If $A$ is not symmetric, use the latter. Also, there should be a $A^\top$ in the latter (otherwise the block matrix is not symmetric).