# On the minimization of the spectral norm

Tags: matrices, optimization, spectral-norm

Given a matrix $\mathbf Z$ and $\mathbf G$, how to solve the following spectral minimization problem?

$$\min_{\mathbf m \in  \mathbb C^n} \|\mathbf Z-\hat{\mathbf Z}\|_2 \quad \text{such that} \quad \hat{\mathbf Z} = \mathbf G \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf m){\mathbf G}^*$$

Can anyone please help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is $Z$ related to $G$, or is it arbitrary? Also, is $Z$ symmetric?

Comment: @VHarisop  is arbitrary and (maybe) symmetric but  might have some structure, like a DFT matrix.

Answer (score 3):

There are some threads, [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075834/formulation-of-spectral-norm-minimization-as-a-semidefinite-program?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136401/spectral-norm-minimization-via-semidefinite-programming?rq=1), about related subjects. The suggested method is to relate $$\min_{w\in \mathbb{C}^n}\|Z-G\,diag(w) G^*\|_2,$$ when you know $Z$ and $G$, to the minimization problem  $$\left\{\begin{array}{rrr}
minimize& x\\subject\,to &\|A(w)\|_2\leq x
\end{array}\right.,$$ with $A(w)=Z-G\,diag(w) G^*$, and $x\geq 0$.

Since $\|A(w)\|_2$ is the [maximum singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Norms_induced_by_p-norms) value $\sigma_{max}(A(w))$ of $A(w)$, it follows that $\|A(w)\|_2\leq x$ is equivalent to $$(\sigma_{max}(A(w)) )^2=\lambda_{max}(A(w)^*A(w))\leq x^2,$$ or $$x^2-\lambda_{max}(A(w)^*A(w))=\lambda_{min}(x^2I-A(w)^*A(w))\geq 0.$$ This means that the matrix $$x^2I-A(w)^*A(w)\geq 0, $$ that is, it is a positive semidefinite matrix. This [implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness) that the block matirx $$\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
xI& A(w)\\A(w)^*&xI
\end{array}\right],$$ is positive semidefinite.

It follows that the initial minimizing problem becomes
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rrr}
 minimize& x\\\\subject\,to &\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
  xI& A(w)\\A(w)^*&xI
 \end{array}\right]\geq 0
\end{array}\right.,$$ with $x\geq 0$, $w\in \mathbb{C}^n$, and $A(w)=Z-G\,diag(w) G^*$. The last one leads you to [Semidefinite programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming#Equivalent_formulations), and you can see this [closed thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670350/operator-norm-calculation-for-simple-matrix/2776808#2776808) about numerical calculations.

Comment: The thread https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294606/nearest-matrix-orthogonally-similar-to-a-given-matrix#answer-294851  has interesting suggestions to numerical procedures and links on matrix optimization. You can find more searching on SearchOnMath.