# Analytic solution of a semidefinite program (SDP)?

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-norms, semidefinite-programming

I am interested in the following optimization problem:
$$
\min_{\lambda > 0} \| \lambda A - I \|_{2},
$$
where $A$ is an arbitrary matrix and $\| \cdot \|_2$ is the spectral norm.

As suggested by [Spectral norm minimization via semidefinite programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136401/spectral-norm-minimization-via-semidefinite-programming), we could write the above problem as the following semidefinite program (SPD):
\begin{align}
&\min_{s,\lambda} s \\
&s.t.\begin{pmatrix} s I & \lambda A - I \\ \lambda A^{\top} - I & s I \end{pmatrix} \succcurlyeq O.
\end{align}
I wonder what next I could do in order to find an analytic solution to the above problem.

What's more, any other method that can solve the original matrix norm minimization problem is appreciated.

Comment: It seems likely that your problem does not have a nice "analytic solution". Do you have any reason to believe that a closed form for the solution exists?

Comment: I just think this problem is a univariate one, and thus may have an analytic solution of some form. Do you have any idea on solving the aforementioned SPD problem? Non-analytic solver is also appreciated.